# What is the technique to make something normal appear abnormal?

Tags: terminology, literary-techniques

I was wondering about the name of the literary/poetic technique where, through examination of tiny details, ordinary actions become abnormal and strange.

For example describing eating as 'the placement of tiny particles along a pronged instrument into a gaping maw.'

Answer (score 1):

It's called [defamiliarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamiliarization):

> Defamiliarization [...] is the artistic technique of presenting to audiences common things in an unfamiliar or strange way so they could gain new perspectives and see the world differently.
>
> Wikipedia